# how can i get the sum when someone click on my buttons and not to join them

Tags: javascript

I have made 3 buttons (10 $, 20 $ ,50$)
and i want when someone clicks a button to add the previous value.
But i get something like this when i click on my buttons 1020502010

Something im doing wrong in this part of the code
// function betBtn()

```
function bet10 () {
    chipbeted.textContent += betc.bet10
    betOn = true
    $('.class').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    console.log(chipbeted.textContent)
}

function bet20 () {
    chipbeted.textContent += betc.bet20 
    betOn = true
    $('.class').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    console.log(chipbeted.textContent)

 
}
function bet50 (){
    chipbeted.textContent += betc.bet50 
    betOn = true
    $('.class').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    console.log(chipbeted.textContent)


}
```

```js
let player = {
    Name : "Nik",
    Chips: 150
}
let cards = []
let sum = 0
let hasBlackjack = false
let isAlive = false
let betOn = false
let betc ={ 
    bet10 : 10,
    bet20 : 20,
    bet50 : 50

}
let message = ""
let messageEl = document.getElementById("message-el")
let totalBet = document.getElementById("chipCount").textContent
let sumEl = document.querySelector("#sum-el")
let cardsEl = document.getElementById("cards-el")
let chipbeted = document.getElementById("chipCount")

let playerEl = document.getElementById("playerEl")
playerEl.textContent = player.Name +":" +" " + player.Chips + "$"


console.log(cards)
function getRandomCard () {
    
    let randomNumer = Math.floor( Math.random()*13 ) + 1
    if (randomNumer > 10) {
        return 10
    } else if (randomNumer === 1) {
        return 11
    } else {
        return randomNumer
    }
}

    


let randomCard = getRandomCard()


function startGame (){
    if (betOn === true){
    isAlive = true
    let firstCard = getRandomCard()
    let secondCard = getRandomCard()
    cards = [firstCard, secondCard]
    sum = firstCard + secondCard
    $('.class').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
    else if (betOn === false){
        document.getElementById("messagewl").textContent = "First, select how many chips you want to BET"
        sum= ""
        
    }
    renderGame()

}

function renderGame(){
    cardsEl.textContent = "Cards: "
    for ( let i=0; i<cards.length ; i++){
        cardsEl.textContent += cards[i]  + " "
    }

    sumEl.textContent = "Sum: " + sum
if ( sum <= 20) {
    console.log(sum)
    message = "Do you want to draw a new card? "  
}
else if ( sum === 21){
    console.log(sum)
    message = "You've got Blackjack!"
    hasBlackjack = true
}
else {
    
    console.log(sum)
    message = "You're out of the game!"
    isAlive = false
}
messageEl.textContent = message
sumEl.textContent = "Sum: " + sum 

}

function cardNew(){

    if (isAlive === true && hasBlackjack === false) {
        let card = getRandomCard()
        sum += card
        cards.push(card)
        console.log(cards)
        renderGame()
    }
    
}  

// function betBtn()

function bet10 () {
    chipbeted.textContent += betc.bet10
    betOn = true
    $('.class').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    console.log(chipbeted.textContent)
}

function bet20 () {
    chipbeted.textContent += betc.bet20 
    betOn = true
    $('.class').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    console.log(chipbeted.textContent)

 
}
function bet50 (){
    chipbeted.textContent += betc.bet50 
    betOn = true
    $('.class').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    console.log(chipbeted.textContent)


}
```

```css
html, body{
    background-image: url("space.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

body {
    color: aliceblue;
    font-family:'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif ; 
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}


#h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 4em;
    display: inline-block;
    background: linear-gradient(246.26deg, #ED4683 0%, #F48E14 100%);
    border-radius: 100px;
    border: 30px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
    
    
}
#buttons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 10px;
}
p{
    font-size: 2em;
}
#btn {
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    background: linear-gradient(246.26deg, #ED4683 0%, #F48E14 100%);
    width:250px;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    color: aliceblue;

}
#btnBet > #btn10,#btn20,#btn50{
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 20 15 0 15;

}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>blackjac Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="h1">
    <h1>Space Blackjack</h1>
        </div>
    <p id="message-el">Want to play a round?</p>
    <p id="cards-el">Cards:</p>
    <p id="sum-el">Sum:</p>
    <p class= "class" id="messagewl"></p>
    <div id="buttons">
        <button id="btn" onclick="startGame()">Start Game</button>
        <button id="btn" onclick="cardNew()">Draw Card</button>
        <button id="btn" onclick="bet()">Bet Chips</button>
        </div>
    <div id="btnBet">
        <button id="btn10" onclick="bet10()">10$</button>
        <button id="btn20" onclick="bet20()">20$</button>
        <button id="btn50" onclick="bet50()">50$</button>
        </div>

        
        <p id="chipCount"></p>
        <p id="playerEl"></p>

        <script src="index.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: `chipbeted.textContent = parseInt(chipbeted.textContent) + betc.bet10`

Comment: Programming is not about copy/pasting functions. Learn about function arguments.

Comment: Don't target nor name elements `'.class'` - it's either totally undescriptive and not something you need. Classes are **reusable**.

Comment: STOP using inline `on*` JS handlers attributes. JS should be in one place only, ant that's the respective file or tag. Use addEventListener instead.

Comment: You are adding text strings, not numbers try to keep numbers and add the $ afterwards, just for display

Comment: Roko C. Buljan
still learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the variable **chipbeted.textContent** returns a string .. that's why you get concatenated result (for example: '20'+10 = 2010 not 30
)..

to solve this problem,

```js
let chipbeted = document.getElementById("chipCount")

let betc = {
  bet10: 10,
  bet20: 20,
  bet50: 50
}

function bet20() {
  chipbeted.textContent = Number(chipbeted.textContent) + betc.bet20
  //betOn = true
  //$('.class').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  //console.log(chipbeted.textContent)
}
```

```html
<button onClick="bet20()">Add bet20</button>

<p id="chipCount"></p>
```

**replace**

```
chipbeted.textContent += betc.bet20
```

in your functions
**with**

```
chipbeted.textContent = Number(chipbeted.textContent) + betc.bet20
```

Comment: but betc.bet20 is already a number! .. you don't have to

Comment: i fixed it guys thank you i had a misspell in one string ! thats the right answer

Comment: I've added a piece of code that you can check if you still have any troubles .. hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Salam . Try this in your function `betBtn()`  :

`chipbeted.textContent=parseInt(chipbeted.textContent)+betc.betBtn ;`

Instead of this :
`chipbeted.textContent += betc.betBtn`

Answer (score -1):

You have to convert the text fields value to Number first, than add the value to it. Otherwise the "+" operator means string concatenation.

**chipbeted.textContent = Number(chipbeted.textContent)+betc.bet20**

```js
let player = {
    Name : "Nik",
    Chips: 150
}
let cards = []
let sum = 0
let hasBlackjack = false
let isAlive = false
let betOn = false
let betc ={ 
    bet10 : 10,
    bet20 : 20,
    bet50 : 50

}
let message = ""
let messageEl = document.getElementById("message-el")
let totalBet = document.getElementById("chipCount").textContent
let sumEl = document.querySelector("#sum-el")
let cardsEl = document.getElementById("cards-el")
let chipbeted = document.getElementById("chipCount")

let playerEl = document.getElementById("playerEl")
playerEl.textContent = player.Name +":" +" " + player.Chips + "$"


console.log(cards)
function getRandomCard () {
    
    let randomNumer = Math.floor( Math.random()*13 ) + 1
    if (randomNumer > 10) {
        return 10
    } else if (randomNumer === 1) {
        return 11
    } else {
        return randomNumer
    }
}

    


let randomCard = getRandomCard()


function startGame (){
    if (betOn === true){
    isAlive = true
    let firstCard = getRandomCard()
    let secondCard = getRandomCard()
    cards = [firstCard, secondCard]
    sum = firstCard + secondCard
    $('.class').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
    else if (betOn === false){
        document.getElementById("messagewl").textContent = "First, select how many chips you want to BET"
        sum= ""
        
    }
    renderGame()

}

function renderGame(){
    cardsEl.textContent = "Cards: "
    for ( let i=0; i<cards.length ; i++){
        cardsEl.textContent += cards[i]  + " "
    }

    sumEl.textContent = "Sum: " + sum
if ( sum <= 20) {
    console.log(sum)
    message = "Do you want to draw a new card? "  
}
else if ( sum === 21){
    console.log(sum)
    message = "You've got Blackjack!"
    hasBlackjack = true
}
else {
    
    console.log(sum)
    message = "You're out of the game!"
    isAlive = false
}
messageEl.textContent = message
sumEl.textContent = "Sum: " + sum 

}

function cardNew(){

    if (isAlive === true && hasBlackjack === false) {
        let card = getRandomCard()
        sum += card
        cards.push(card)
        console.log(cards)
        renderGame()
    }
    
}  

// function betBtn()

function bet10 () {
    chipbeted.textContent = Number(chipbeted.textContent)+betc.bet10;
    betOn = true
    $('.class').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    console.log(chipbeted.textContent)
}

function bet20 () {
    chipbeted.textContent = Number(chipbeted.textContent)+betc.bet20 ;
    betOn = true
    $('.class').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    console.log(chipbeted.textContent)

 
}
function bet50 (){
    chipbeted.textContent = Number(chipbeted.textContent)+betc.bet50;
    betOn = true
    $('.class').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    console.log(chipbeted.textContent)


}
```

```css
html, body{
    background-image: url("space.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

body {
    color: aliceblue;
    font-family:'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif ; 
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}


#h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 4em;
    display: inline-block;
    background: linear-gradient(246.26deg, #ED4683 0%, #F48E14 100%);
    border-radius: 100px;
    border: 30px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
    
    
}
#buttons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 10px;
}
p{
    font-size: 2em;
}
#btn {
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    background: linear-gradient(246.26deg, #ED4683 0%, #F48E14 100%);
    width:250px;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    color: aliceblue;

}
#btnBet > #btn10,#btn20,#btn50{
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 20 15 0 15;

}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>blackjac Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="h1">
    <h1>Space Blackjack</h1>
        </div>
    <p id="message-el">Want to play a round?</p>
    <p id="cards-el">Cards:</p>
    <p id="sum-el">Sum:</p>
    <p class= "class" id="messagewl"></p>
    <div id="buttons">
        <button id="btn" onclick="startGame()">Start Game</button>
        <button id="btn" onclick="cardNew()">Draw Card</button>
        <button id="btn" onclick="bet()">Bet Chips</button>
        </div>
    <div id="btnBet">
        <button id="btn10" onclick="bet10()">10$</button>
        <button id="btn20" onclick="bet20()">20$</button>
        <button id="btn50" onclick="bet50()">50$</button>
        </div>

        
        <p id="chipCount"></p>
        <p id="playerEl"></p>

        <script src="index.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: like this i got the write result but why it has dislikes ? its not the right way to do it?

Comment: I dont know...Maybe because its too long because i inserted your modified snippet.